# php every 1st and 4th (onwards) add a class

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to change a class on a div within a foreach loop.. I need the first item to have `col-md-12` and then the next two to be `col-md-6` and back to the start again..

```
col-md-12
col-md-6 col-md-6
col-md-12
col-md-6 col-md-6
col-md-12
col-md-6 col-md-6
```

Here's what I've done, which isn't doing it for the first item:

```
<?php $j=0;foreach ($value as $item) : $linky = ''; ?>                  
    <div class="grid-item <?php if ($j % 3 == 1) : ?>col-md-12<?php else : ?>col-md-6<?php endif; ?>">
        xxx
    </div>
<?php $j++;endforeach; ?>
```

This is giving me

```
col-md-6 (i want this one to be col-md-12)
col-md-12
col-md-6 col-md-6
col-md-12
col-md-6 col-md-6
```

Comment: Test for `$j % 3 === 0`, not 1

Comment: Yep thanks, that worked. Ugh it's late in the day, i'm done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using `foreach`:

```
<?php $j=0;foreach ($value as $item) : $linky = ''; ?>                  
    <div class="grid-item <?php if ($j % 3 === 0) : ?>col-md-12<?php else : ?>col-md-6<?php endif; ?>">
        xxx
    </div>
<?php $j++;endforeach; ?>
```

You can also use the following solution using `for`:

```
<?php for ($j = 0; $j < count($value); $j++) : $linky = ''; ?>                  
    <div class="grid-item <?php if ($j % 3 === 0) : ?>col-md-12<?php else : ?>col-md-6<?php endif; ?>">
        xxx
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

What is the difference between `0` and `1`:

```
index ($j) | $j % 3 === 1 | $j % 3 === 0
----------------------------------------
         0 | false        | true
         1 | false        | false
         2 | false        | false
         3 | false        | true
         4 | true         | false
         5 | false        | false
         6 | false        | true
         7 | true         | false
```